# How to read Logs In jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I added " Access log Sampler" in my test plan and i get the logs as follows

```
1448892504061,2131,806 /,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,21945,1,1,1953
1448892506225,385,809 /aluminium.html,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,30911,1,1,210
1448892506615,389,811 /titanium.html,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,31369,1,1,207
1448892507008,366,851 /titanium/titanium-axle-adjuster-bolt-m8-x-45mm-nut-4.html,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,27321,1,1,200
1448892507381,609,872 /checkout/cart/,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,15289,1,1,403
1448892508003,3227,877 /checkout/onepage/,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,16812,1,1,2478
1448892511246,171,880 /js/varien/accordion.js,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,1653,1,1,171
1448892511424,346,881 /skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,6113,1,1,346
```

But i am unable to understand clearly

Can anyone help to know how to understand the error or failure of system.

Comment: It seems 200 indicates page request successful as per logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use listener to understand the Logs.

Please refer below steps

1. Right click "thread group” add -> listener -> aggregate report
2. Now select your Access Log Sampler
   [image]
3. Enter the IP Address or hostname
4. Enter the port
5. If you want to download the images, set "Parse images" to true
6. Select a file for "log file location"
   [image]
7. Select the aggregate report
8. Enter "results.jtl" for filename
9. Now you can run the script and get the logs explained in the aggregate report.

**Note** : You can use different reports instead of the aggregate report depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure jmeter to add an header line with the column names by modifying the `jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names` to `true` in the `jmeter.properties` file.

By default, the columns are:

```
timeStamp        - unix timestamp of the request
elapsed          - time elapsed
label            - a label (page title or url)
responseCode     - http response code
responseMessage  - http response message
threadName       - name of the jave thread that did the request
dataType         - mime type of the response
success          - boolean, true if request successful
bytes            - size of the response body
Latency          - latency in ms
```